# Accessing post custom variables within a plugin - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've tried the following method within a plugin:

```
get_post_meta($featuredPosts[$i]->ID, "Thumbnail", true);
```

within the following plugin code:

```
$featuredPosts = new WP_Query();
$featuredPosts->query('showposts=5&cat=1');

for($i=1; $i<=$featuredPosts; $i++) { // second for() loop for post slides
      while ($featuredPosts->have_posts()) : $featuredPosts->the_post(); // loop for posts

           get_post_meta($featuredPosts[$i]->ID, "Thumbnail", true);

      endwhile;
}
```

unfortunately this doesn't return any values :(

---

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using the following to get the post ID:

```
$featuredPosts->posts[$i]->ID
```